# Loopback autoupdate not creating custom models

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to create an app using Loopback (V3) and i've encountered a weird error.

I'm trying to create my Mysql tables using `autoupdate()`, but for my custom models it is not working.

This is what i've tried so far ->

```
var server = require('../server');
var ds = server.dataSources.db;

var models = ['test','Post','User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];

ds.isActual(models, function(err, actual) {
  if (!actual) {
    ds.autoupdate(null, function(err,result){
      console.log("DONE!");
      console.log(result);
    });
  };
});
```

The script works. If the database is empty it will create tables for all EXCEPT `test` and `Post`. Those are my custom models, the others are built into loopback.

Is it because of model type? (tried Model and PersistedModel) or is it something else? I even tried without the `isActual` check and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you keep two separate arrays for built-in models and custom models and write code like following, that way you could know where the issue is. also, I think there is an error in your code near ds.autoupdate(null, fun.....
please follow according to the below code

```
var builtInModels = ['AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping','Role'];
var userDefinedModels = ['Post','test'];
// migrate built-in models
dataSource.isActual(builtInModels, function (err, actual) {
  if (!actual) {
    dataSource.autoupdate(builtInModels, function (err, result) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      console.log('Datasource Synced: Built in models');
    });
  }
});

// migrate userdefined models
dataSource.isActual(userDefinedModels, function (err, actual) {
  if (!actual) {
    dataSource.autoupdate(userDefinedModels, function (err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log('Datasource Synced: User defined models');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to work, with errors. May i ask how do the `userDefinedModels` and `builtInModels` vars look like? Are they arrays like i posted above or something else? Can please update with that info. The thing is it creates the db for posts now (I added the `Post` model as an array item), but throws an error in `builtInModels` such as `cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` inside `loopback-connector`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the vars of arrays as requested, also I got your error - you may not have defined Post and test model in the model-config.json file, please verify for the same

Comment: Good thing mentioning model-config.json. I recreated the LB project just to test your answer (im trying versions till i'm sure what to start work on) and forgot to edit the `dataSource` for the built in models in my `model-config.json`. Btw you forgot `User` inside the builtInModels array. Anyway, i added everything, works with 0 errors, many thanks! Now i need to decide if i should wait for LB4 ACL/Auth or go with the older LB3.